# Install module in customize location

Tags: python, python-2.7, sympy

I have installed python module sympy at my one directory name modules and trying to append into
sys.path. As per I know, I should be able to import module.But I end up with ImportError Am I doing some mistake.

```
import sys
sys.path.append("modules")
print sys.path
import sympy
```

> Purpose : I want to install locally and do not stored into python global location
>   I have tried with Insert also but none of these working

I have changed the above code with Following way and works But could not understand why is first version not working.

```
import sys
print sys.prefix
sys.path.insert(0, "modules/lib/python")
print sys.path
import sympy
```

Comment: Can you see your full directory path when you do `print sys.path`?

Comment: Yes <location>/modules

Comment: I don't see any problem then except one: if it's a package and reside under directory do you have `__init__.py` file under that directory?

Comment: Yes. it contain modules/lib/python/sympy/__init_.py

Comment: Try setting the `PYTHONPATH` variable in bash.